# How properly encode accents for display in REST/JSON response and printStackTrace?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, localization

I am returning a localized error message in a JSON response and printing it to logs. When I do this, both show weird, messed up characters. How can I encode the message to properly display non-English characters?

The message as stored in `"messages_fr.properties"`:

```
exceptions.generalMessage=Un problème est survenu lors de la gestion de votre demande.
```

How it appears in the JSON response:

```
"message": "Un problÃ¨me est survenu lors de la gestion de votre demande."
```

It appears the same as above in the stack trace.

Comment: Have you tried storing the actual UTF-8 representation for that character in `messages_fr.properties`? It works for me for message(s) in Spanish; like: `Un problema de gestión`...and that's stored as `Un problema de gesti\u00f3n`.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ How do I store it in UTF-8?

Comment: It comes out like this: `Un problxC3xA8me est survenu lors de la gestion de votre demande.`. I stored it in the UTF-8: `Un probl\xC3\xA8me est survenu lors de la gestion de votre demande.`

Comment: Nah...yours should be something like: `Un probl\u00E8me est survenu...`; also make sure you are indeed storing that file in UTF-8, Spring has that setting (in `application.properties` or similar): `spring.messages.encoding = UTF-8`...and (maybe) that you are returning the response, as @Optional said, in UTF-8. For me, the first two are enough since the response is changed downstream in Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating Json response? Is it a jersey server?

1. If it's server, then add the encodin to your `@Produces` tag.

   `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")`
2. If it's Jackson ObjectMapper, then it shall work by default like this

   ```
       Map m = new HashMap();
       m.put("error", "Un problème est survenu lors de la gestion de votre demande.");
       com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper mapper = new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper();
       System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(m));
   ```